# Is there such a thing as a combination of linear and non-linear regression in one form?

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

Let's say I have a dataset `D` with many variables. I can get a multiple linear regression from that in the form `Y=M1X1+M2X2+M3X3+...+MnXn+B`. I can also get a multiple non-linear regression by taking `ln(D)` then performing a normal multiple linear regression and raising the final product up by `e` to get something in the form of: `Y=X1^(W1)*X2^(W2)*X3^(W3)*...*Xn^(Wn)*C`.

Now for the titular question: is there a mixed form that involves both linear and non-linear components? Where would I start to learn more?

Comment: Computers are available. Stop considering linearization by logarthming of the data and perform some propper nonlinear regression. Please.

Comment: @V-X I understand your argument, but one also has to keep in mind that even computers sometimes have difficulty solving non-linear regressions. Furthermore, depending on the complexity of the problem, the amount of time and resources needed to find a solution might not be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is something similar to what you have in mind?

Let $Y=e^{X_1\beta_1}*X_2^{\beta_2}*X_3^{\beta_3} $

Taking logs of both sides yields:

$ ln(Y) = X_1\beta_1 + \beta_2ln(X_2) + \beta_3ln(X_3) $

which contains both a linear ($X_1\beta_1$) and non-linear ($\beta_2ln(X_2) + \beta_3ln(X_3) $) components.

One place we see these a lot is in Duration Models